# How can I std::sqrt(boost::lambda::placeholder1_type)?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda

How do I `std::sqrt()` on a `boost::lambda::placeholder1_type`?

The following program compiles and executes fine. Somehow, it manages to convert `boost::lambda::_1` to a double and multiply it with 5.0.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

  std::array<double, 6> a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36};

  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(),
      std::cout << boost::lambda::_1 * 5.0 << " "
  );
}
```

However, if I replace the `std::cout` line with

```
std::cout << std::sqrt(boost::lambda::_1) << " "
```

the compiler (g++) says

> no known conversion for argument 1 from
>   ‘boost::lambda::placeholder1_type {aka const
>   boost::lambda::lambda_functor >}’ to
>   ‘double’

So, how can I take the square root from `boost::lambda::_1` in this std::for_each loop?

Comment: What do you think boost::lambda::_1 is doing there?

Comment: Question: why use Boost.Lambda when you have C++11?

Comment: If you want to call a function, then it seems you should use a [bind expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delay the call of `sqrt`. To achieve this, you should use a
[bind expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/lambda/le_in_details.html#lambda.bind_expressions).

NB: You need to use a cast to select the correct `sqrt` overload.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    std::array<double, 6> a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36};

    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(),
        std::cout << boost::lambda::bind(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::sqrt), boost::lambda::_1) << " "
    );
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

<kbd>[Live Sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c86e6c579d23cc1)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Do it the C++11 way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

  std::array<double, 6> a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36};

  std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(),
      [] (const auto&v ) { std::cout << sqrt(v) * 5.0 << " "; }
  );
}
```

Comment: Range-based for loop would have been simpler for this use case.

Comment: It does not answer OP's question.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP also tagged the question C++11. Which is quite confusing since boost::lambda was meant to replicate the now standardized feature.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the good old days of Boost.Lambda

```
int main() {

    std::array<double, 6> a = {1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36};

    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(),
        std::cout << boost::lambda::bind(static_cast<double(*)(double)>(std::sqrt), boost::lambda::_1 * 5.0) << " "
    );
    return 0;
}
```